# How can I set a (Google Analytics) Content Experiment (A/B test) with a singular URL?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to test whether a variant of my current homepage will perform better (reach a certain goal defined on GA), but I'm struggling to find a good solution.

Let's say the current version (Original) has sections A, B, C in that order. The other version (Variant), though, has sections in the order B, C, A. Note: the top navigation menu (linking to each section's anchor) must reflect this change.

I first considered Client-Side Experiments, which I have done in the past, but I'm worried those wouldn't look good when rendering the site: depending on loading speed, a Variant user would first see section A, and then they would see section A vanish (into the bottom of the page), while they could also notice the menu being changed.

I then considered the regular Experiment mode on Analytics, which asks me to determine two URLs to compare: the Original is my root path (e.g. `http://mywebsite.xyz/`) and the Variant would be something like `http://mywebsite.xyz/home`. But I can't orientate half of my users to this different URL - I want to test people who reach my homepage from wherever they may come.

I tried something through the Google Cloud App Engine: publishing two versions of my application, and splitting traffic 50/50 between both (cookie-based). When visiting the root path, one renders the Original, while the other renders the Variant version. Great. It works! But now Google Analytics has no idea which version it's tracking...

What I did: when the page first loads, I send an event with the version identifier as parameter, such as

```
ga('send', 'event', 'AB_Test', 'A');
// or
ga('send', 'event', 'AB_Test', 'B');
```

I suppose these would help me check the Events Flow and determine which version reaches more Event goals, but it's still not linked to an Experiment or its features.

Is there any better way to implement this? Am I missing something? It feels too complicated to do something that both the Cloud App Engine and the Analytics should help me achieve. (Thanks for reading, I know it's a huge text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this type of experiment, I typically try to leverage the API to determine the variation in the backend and then render the template appropriately.

For your current workaround, rather than sending events, I'd recommend instantiating the test on each server and manually setting the variant for each.  See code below:

```js
<!-- App 1 / Original -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=<EXPERIMENT ID>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    cxApi.setChosenVariation(0);
  }());
</script>

<!-- App 2 / Variant -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=<EXPERIMENT ID>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    cxApi.setChosenVariation(1);
  }());
</script>
```